# Cancelling the hover feature of sap.m.List?

Tags: list, hover, sapui5

What effects the Hover feature of the sap.m.List ?
I'm trying to cancel the color changing when hover one of the list items

Comment: The hover effect is enabled in selection mode: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.List/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelection. Turn the selection mode off to disable hover effect. Otherwise, I'd suggest to keep the hover effect in order to align with the Fiori design guideline.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you'd like to remove the hover effect?

Comment: I added style class to the selected items in the list, and when I hover, the Css is gone... That's why I want to cancel this feature

Answer (score 1):

Hover Property is the default behaviour of the sap.m.List control and it lets you know which ListItem you are trying to select when "mode" property is set for selection. It's a nice User Experience to have.

However, if you want to change the colour of hover you can do it by using CSS. You can make it to match the background which appears as nothing happens on hover.

```
.myCustomListClass .sapMLIBHoverable:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```